# Using SPServices to get Choice Column options

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I would like to create a custom modal that has the same drop down items that are contained in the choice column when adding a new item. My page is a custom .html and does not load the default SharePoint files. My column name is

```
Entry: Notice or Information or Error
```

I used this example as a starting point [SPServices: populate a drop-down menu](http://www.bentedder.com/spservices-example-populate-a-drop-down-menu/)
I have it working, however I wanted the choices contained in the column so that the modal will have them as well. Any direction is appreciated my Google results haven’t really retuned anything using just SPServices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is several months old but I was looking to do something similar.  I found my answer here: https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/using-spservices-to-get-the-values-of-a-choice-field/

Basically the code looks like this:

```
    function GetChoicesFromField() {
       var method = "GetList";
       var webURL = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
       var list = "<name of your list>";

       $().SPServices({
          operation: method,
          listName: list,
          completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            parseSiteField(xData, Status);
          },
          async: false
        });
      }

      function parseSiteField(xData, Status) {
         if (Status == 'success') {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Field[DisplayName='<column name>'] CHOICE").each(function () {
                console.log($(this).text())
             });
          }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you this is still relevant to me and now I can simplify my code.